# How do I add a UIActivityIndicatorView to footer of UICollectionView?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, footer, uiactivityindicatorview

How do I add a `UIActivityIndicatorView` to footer of `UICollectionView` in swift? For `UITableView`, it was just `self.tableView.tableFootView = self.myActivityIndicatorView`. Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Create view class and add activity indication in that view

Register this class as footer view class using:

```
registerClass(myFooterViewClass, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter, withReuseIdentifier: "myFooterView")
```

Either set the headerReferenceSize on your collection view layout or implement

```
collectionView:layout:referenceSizeForHeaderInSection: in your delegate.
```

Return the footer view from the following method in your dataSource:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
let view = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter, withReuseIdentifier: "myFooterView", forIndexPath: indexPath)
// configure footer view
return view
}
```